# Erro no calculo - Flutter

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

Estou quebrando a cabeça em um problema que está dando no meu debug em um aplicativo meu que é o seguinte:

> "The method '>' was called on null.Receiver: null Tried calling: >(0)"

Segue o código para verificação

```
    void calculate() {
    double totp1 = double.parse(precoController1.text) * 12;
    double totmlp1 = double.parse(unidadeController1.text) * 12;
    double totp2 = double.parse(precoController2.text) * 12;
    double totmlp2 = double.parse(unidadeController2.text) * 12;

    double difvalor;
    double latas;
    double litros;
    double totlitros;
    double diflitros;

    if (totp1 > totp2) {
      difvalor = totp1 - totp2;
      latas = (difvalor / double.parse(precoController2.text));
      litros = (latas * double.parse(unidadeController2.text));
      totlitros = litros + totmlp2;
      diflitros = totlitros - totmlp1;
    }
    if (diflitros > (0))
      print('Pelo mesmo preço do Produto 1 você leva $latas' +
          'latas do Produto 2, e ganha mais $diflitros' +
          'Mls');
    else if (diflitros < (0))
      print('Compensa comprar o Produto 1');
    else if (diflitros == (0))
      print('Levando o Produto 2, mais $latas' +
          'fica o mesmo que levar o produto 1');
    else {
      difvalor = totp2 - totp1;
      latas = (difvalor / double.parse(precoController1.text));
      litros = (latas * double.parse(unidadeController1.text));
      totlitros = litros + totmlp1;
      diflitros = totlitros - totmlp2;
    }

    if (diflitros > (0))
      print('Pelo mesmo preço do Produto 2 você leva $latas' +
          'latas do Produto 1, e ganha mais $diflitros' +
          'Mls');
    else if (diflitros < (0))
      print('Compensa comprar o Produto 2');
    else if (diflitros == (0))
      print('Levando o Produto 1, mais $latas' +
          'fica o mesmo que levar o produto 1');
  }
```

Comment: Mesmo que você declarar `diflitros` como `double`, se você não inicializar a variável explicitamente com `0`, Dart irá inicializa-la como `null`, por isso `diflitros > (0)` lança uma exceção, pois a comparação `null > 0` não é válida.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem... Como seria essa exceção?

Answer (score 2):

Você declarou a `diflitros` mas não iniciou ela. Por padrão quando uma variável é declarada e não é instanciada ela é setada como `null`. Ao fazer as validações nos ifs Ex:

```
if (diflitros > (0))
```

`diflitros` está nulo, e ele vai tentar fazer a comparação de null > (0) e isso não é válido. Por isso é disparado uma exception.

Comment: Muito obrigado, entendi o problema.